# Spring dependency issue - no matching editors or conversion strategy found

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, spring-ioc

I have a web application which fails while deployment. I get following error:

```
Aug 8, 2014 7:00:21 PM org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader initWebApplicationContext
SEVERE: Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.filterChains': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'org.springframework.security.web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain#2' while setting bean property 'sourceList' with key [2]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain#2': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter#0' while setting constructor argument with key [3]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter#0': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'CustomLoginSuccessHandler' while setting bean property 'authenticationSuccessHandler'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'CustomLoginSuccessHandler': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: com.abc.xyz.ldapservices.LDAPUtil com.abc.xyz.web.CustomLoginSuccessHandler.ldapContact; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'ldapContact' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring/spring-security.xml]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.ConversionNotSupportedException: Failed to convert property value of type '$Proxy213 implementing org.springframework.ldap.core.LdapOperations,org.springframework.beans.factory.InitializingBean,org.springframework.aop.SpringProxy,org.springframework.aop.framework.Advised' to required type 'org.springframework.ldap.core.LdapTemplate' for property 'ldapTemplate'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type [$Proxy213 implementing org.springframework.ldap.core.LdapOperations,org.springframework.beans.factory.InitializingBean,org.springframework.aop.SpringProxy,org.springframework.aop.framework.Advised] to required type [org.springframework.ldap.core.LdapTemplate] for property 'ldapTemplate': no matching editors or conversion strategy found
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:329)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:107)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveManagedList(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:353)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:154)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1391)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1132)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:522)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:461)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:295)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:223)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:292)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:589)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:932)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:479)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:383)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:283)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:112)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.EventsManager$FireContextListenerAction.run(EventsManager.java:661)
    at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:321)
    at weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAs(SecurityManager.java:120)
    at weblogic.servlet.provider.WlsSubjectHandle.run(WlsSubjectHandle.java:57)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.EventsManager.executeContextListener(EventsManager.java:241)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.EventsManager.notifyContextCreatedEvent(EventsManager.java:198)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.EventsManager.notifyContextCreatedEvent(EventsManager.java:183)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.preloadResources(WebAppServletContext.java:1783)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.start(WebAppServletContext.java:2807)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppModule.startContexts(WebAppModule.java:1661)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppModule.start(WebAppModule.java:822)
    at weblogic.application.internal.ExtensibleModuleWrapper$StartStateChange.next(ExtensibleModuleWrapper.java:360)
    at weblogic.application.internal.ExtensibleModuleWrapper$StartStateChange.next(ExtensibleModuleWrapper.java:356)
    at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:42)
    at weblogic.application.internal.ExtensibleModuleWrapper.start(ExtensibleModuleWrapper.java:138)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleListenerInvoker.start(ModuleListenerInvoker.java:124)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$3.next(ModuleStateDriver.java:213)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$3.next(ModuleStateDriver.java:208)
    at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:42)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver.start(ModuleStateDriver.java:70)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.StartModulesFlow.activate(StartModulesFlow.java:24)
    at weblogic.application.internal.BaseDeployment$2.next(BaseDeployment.java:729)
    at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:42)
    at weblogic.application.internal.BaseDeployment.activate(BaseDeployment.java:258)
    at weblogic.application.internal.SingleModuleDeployment.activate(SingleModuleDeployment.java:48)
    at weblogic.application.internal.DeploymentStateChecker.activate(DeploymentStateChecker.java:165)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.AppContainerInvoker.activate(AppContainerInvoker.java:80)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.AbstractOperation.activate(AbstractOperation.java:586)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.ActivateOperation.activateDeployment(ActivateOperation.java:148)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.ActivateOperation.doCommit(ActivateOperation.java:114)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.AbstractOperation.commit(AbstractOperation.java:339)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentManager.handleDeploymentCommit(DeploymentManager.java:846)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentManager.activateDeploymentList(DeploymentManager.java:1275)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentManager.handleCommit(DeploymentManager.java:442)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentServiceDispatcher.commit(DeploymentServiceDispatcher.java:176)
    at weblogic.deploy.service.internal.targetserver.DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.doCommitCallback(DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.java:195)
    at weblogic.deploy.service.internal.targetserver.DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.access$100(DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.java:13)
    at weblogic.deploy.service.internal.targetserver.DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer$2.run(DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.java:68)
    at weblogic.work.SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl$WorkAdapterImpl.run(SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.java:550)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:295)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:254)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain#2': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter#0' while setting constructor argument with key [3]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter#0': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'CustomLoginSuccessHandler' while setting bean property 'authenticationSuccessHandler'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'CustomLoginSuccessHandler': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: com.abc.xyz.ldapservices.LDAPUtil com.abc.xyz.web.CustomLoginSuccessHandler.ldapContact; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'ldapContact' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring/spring-security.xml]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.ConversionNotSupportedException: Failed to convert property value of type '$Proxy213 implementing org.springframework.ldap.core.LdapOperations,org.springframework.beans.factory.InitializingBean,org.springframework.aop.SpringProxy,org.springframework.aop.framework.Advised' to required type 'org.springframework.ldap.core.LdapTemplate' for property 'ldapTemplate'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type [$Proxy213 implementing org.springframework.ldap.core.LdapOperations,org.springframework.beans.factory.InitializingBean,org.springframework.aop.SpringProxy,org.springframework.aop.framework.Advised] to required type [org.springframework.ldap.core.LdapTemplate] for property 'ldapTemplate': no matching editors or conversion strategy found
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:329)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:107)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveManagedList(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:353)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:154)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveConstructorArguments(ConstructorResolver.java:615)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:148)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1049)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:953)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:490)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:461)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:295)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:223)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:292)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:323)
```

I am loading my configuration XML's in **web.xml** using:

```
<context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>
            WEB-INF/spring/spring-security.xml
            WEB-INF/spring/applicationContext-db.xml
            WEB-INF/spring/applicationContext.xml
        </param-value>
    </context-param>
```

The error comes from my **spring-security.xml** file, which has :

```
<security:http auto-config="true" use-expressions="true"
        access-denied-page="/auth/denied">
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/auth/login"
            access="permitAll" />
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/main/admin"
            access="hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')" />
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/main/common"
            access="hasRole('ROLE_RI')" />

        <security:form-login login-page="/auth/login"
            authentication-failure-url="/auth/login?error=true"
            default-target-url="/main/common" authentication-success-handler-ref="CustomLoginSuccessHandler" />


        <security:logout invalidate-session="true" logout-url="/auth/logout"
            success-handler-ref="CustomLogoutSuccessHandler" />

    </security:http>

    <bean id="CustomLoginSuccessHandler"
        class="com.abc.xyz.web.CustomLoginSuccessHandler">
        <property name="ldapContact" ref="ldapContact"></property>
    </bean>
    <bean id="CustomLogoutSuccessHandler"
        class="com.abc.xyz.web.CustomLogoutSuccessHandler">
    </bean>

    <security:authentication-manager>
        <security:ldap-authentication-provider
            user-search-filter="(uid={0})" user-search-base="ou=Users"
            group-search-filter="(roleOccupant={0})" group-search-base="ou=Groups"
            group-role-attribute="cn" role-prefix="ROLE_">
        </security:ldap-authentication-provider>
    </security:authentication-manager>

    <security:ldap-server url="ldap://localhost:389/dc=maxcrc,dc=com"
        manager-dn="cn=Manager,dc=maxcrc,dc=com" manager-password="secret" />

    <security:global-method-security
        secured-annotations="enabled" />

<!--    <bean id="placeHolderConfigurer" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
        <property name="systemPropertiesModeName" value="SYSTEM_PROPERTIES_MODE_OVERRIDE"/>
        <property name="location" value="/WEB-INF/classes/ldap.properties"></property>
    </bean> 
  <context:property-placeholder location="classpath:WEB-INF/classes/ldap.properties"/>
-->
    <bean id="contextSource"
        class="org.springframework.security.ldap.DefaultSpringSecurityContextSource">
        <constructor-arg value="ldap://localhost:389/dc=maxcrc,dc=com" />
        <property name="userDn" value="cn=Manager,dc=maxcrc,dc=com" />
        <property name="password" value="secret" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="ldapTemplate" class="org.springframework.ldap.core.LdapTemplate">
        <constructor-arg ref="contextSource" />
        <property name="ignorePartialResultException" value="true" />
    </bean>
    <bean id="ldapContact" class="com.abc.xyz.ldapservices.LDAPUtil">
        <property name="ldapTemplate" ref="ldapTemplate" />
    </bean>
```

My **CustomLoginSuccessHandler** class is like:

```
public class CustomLoginSuccessHandler implements AuthenticationSuccessHandler {


    /** The redirect strategy. */
    private RedirectStrategy redirectStrategy = new DefaultRedirectStrategy();

    /** The ldap contact. */
    @Autowired
    LDAPUtil ldapContact;
```

I am new to spring but i guess it is due to the bean dependencies configuration.

**1. What is the sequence of spring bean dependency, does it uses
    sequence of XML configuration from web.xml?

 2. Suppose I refer bean A
    in a XML file, which is defined below where it is refered, will it
    create any problem?**

**EDIT**

My LDAPUtil class is like:

```
private LdapOperations ldapTemplate;

public void setLdapTemplate(LdapTemplate ldapTemplate) {
            this.ldapTemplate = ldapTemplate;
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The  error gives useful elements. The cause (last error in chain) is (stripped down string) :

> Error creating bean with name 'ldapContact' ... Failed to convert property value of type '$Proxy213 implementing ... LdapOperations ...' to required type '....LdapTemplate' for property 'ldapTemplate'

You did not show `LdapUtil` source, but from `CustomSuccessHandler` and the error, I presume it contains somewhere :

```
@Autowired
LdapTemplate ldapTemplate;
```

The error indicates that there is an AOP proxying mechanisme around the `ldapTemplate`bean.

It is not a problem, except that by default Spring AOP uses JDK proxies, and a proxy implements all interfaces, but does not extends the original class. You should be able to fix the error by referencing `ldapTemplate` through an interface :

```
@Autowired
LdapOperations ldapTemplate;
```

Alternatively, you can ask Spring to use cglib proxies, that do extend original class by using `<aop:config proxy-target-class = "true">` in xml file (or `<aop:aspectj-autoproxy proxy-target-class="true"/>` if you are using annotations). But that requires cglib jars to be on the path, and as you can use interfaces, I advice you to use first solution.

EDIT :

Your edited post shows how you load `ldapTemplate` in `LdapUtil`. You load it as a class, when you should use the interface that way :

```
private LdapOperations ldapTemplate;

public void setLdapTemplate(LdapOperations ldapTemplate) {
            this.ldapTemplate = ldapTemplate;
}
```

Comment: Tried the interface way which you suggested, but it is still giving me the same error, I also tried change org.springframework.ldap.core.LdapTemplate to org.springframework.ldap.core.LdapOperations in xml, but it then gives me constructor exception.

Comment: If you write `@Autowired LdapOperations ldapTemplate;` in `LdapUtil.java` and do a clean rebuild you cannot get same error. Maybe another, but not *Failed to convert ... to required type '....LdapTemplate'* for bean `ldapContact`

Comment: I do not have @Autowired annotation for ldapTemplate as I have defined the bean for LdapUtil.java in my spring-security.xml file itself.